# Best Design Pattern to execute steps in python

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns

I have to execute multiple actions sequentially in an order dependant manner.

```
StepOne(arg1, arg2).execute()
StepTwo(arg1, arg2).execute()
StepThree(arg1, arg2).execute()
StepFour(arg1, arg2).execute()
StepFive(arg1, arg2).execute()
```

They all inherit from the same `Step` class and receive the same 2 args.

```
class Step:
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2

    def execute(self):
        raise NotImplementedError('This is an "abstract" method!')
```

What's the most idiomatic way to execute these actions in order? Is there a design pattern that would apply here?

Comment: Why are these objects instead of just functions?

Comment: They execute more than one query. They are steps for different kind of updates and inserts.

Comment: I don't recall what talk it's from, but there's a quote I like: "If you have a class with just one method, you have a method." The class adds nothing.

Comment: I agree! But each 'execute' is calling its own chain of methods in my case. :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could create a list of the step classes, then instantiate and call them in a loop.

```
step_classes = [StepOne, StepTwo, StepThree, ...]

for c in step_classes:
    c(arg1, arg2).execute()
```

Comment: I might do `for step in map(lambda c: c(arg1, arg2), step_classes): step.execute()`, but it really doesn't matter. I just like the separation of concerns.

Comment: Cool! I didn't know that 'classes' could be stored inside a list! I'm not really 'creating' these objects in memory before I run the for loop right?

Comment: @RodrigoNey Exactly. You're just storing a list of class types. They don't get created until `c(arg1, arg2)`.